# Nifi 1.10 STATELESS -Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: apache-nifi, stateless

**RUN THIS COMMAND**

```
/bin/nifi.sh stateless RunFromRegistry Once --file ./test/stateless_test1.json
```

**LOG**

```
Note: Use of this command is considered experimental. The commands and approach used may change from time to time.
Java home (JAVA_HOME): /home/deltaman/software/jdk1.8.0_211
Java options (STATELESS_JAVA_OPTS): -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
13:48:39.835 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.StatelessNiFi - Unpacking 100 NARs
13:50:51.513 [main] INFO org.apache.nifi.StatelessNiFi - Finished unpacking 100 NARs in 131671 millis
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.StatelessNiFi.main(StatelessNiFi.java:103)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ./test/stateless_test1.json
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
    at org.apache.nifi.stateless.runtimes.Program.runLocal(Program.java:119)
    at org.apache.nifi.stateless.runtimes.Program.launch(Program.java:67)
    ... 10 more
```

**it seems no exist file,but i can find the file as follows:**

```
$ cat ./test/stateless_test1.json 
{
  "registryUrl": "http://10.148.123.12:9991",
  "bucketId": "ec1b291e-c3f1-437c-a4e4-c069bd2f6ed1",
  "flowId": "b1f73fe8-2874-47a5-970c-6b25eea19497",
  "parameters": {
    "text" : "xixixixi"
  }
}
```

**CONFIGURATION**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

IDK WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?
ANY SUGGESTION IS APPRECIATION!

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/nifi.sh stateless RunFromRegistry Once --file ./test/stateless_test1.json
```

it is relative path,must use full path,such as

`/home/NiFi/nifi-1.10.0/bin/nifi.sh stateless RunFromRegistry Once --file /home/NiFi/nifi-1.10.0/test/stateless_test1.json`